Как сделать простую форму в SAP Logon?
Установил SAP Trial. Контейнер развернут на сервере и SAP Logon установлен на ПК.
Мне нужно для теста сделать форму с разными типами полями - дата, текст, файл... Любую форму которую я могу открыть, заполнить и сохранить.
Реально это сделать без глубокого знания SAP и ABAP? И подскажите пожалуйста либо материал либо примерный алгоритм действий по созданию простой формы?
Мне нужно понять с чего мне начать, чтобы выполнить эту задачу быстро.
